# how return an IEnumerable<> of my customized model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ienumerable

I am using EF6 and one of my models name is tblAttachLabel. and I have customized model that name is AttachLabel. I need an IEnumerable of my customized model that fill with tblAttachLabel Model. It is very easy to return

```
IEnumerable<tblAttachLabel>
```

from my function but I need to return

```
IEnumerable<AttachLabel>
```

so I do this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
    {            
        Entities db = new Entities();
        var x = from al in db.tblAttachLabels select al;

        List<AttachLabel> temp = new List<AttachLabel>();
        IEnumerable<AttachLabel> _attachLabel;
        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            AttachLabel a = new AttachLabel()
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Text = item.Text
            };
            temp.Add(a);
        }
        _attachLabel = temp;

        return _attachLabel;
    }
```

but I know when I use a List for temp the query will execute, but I dont want this. so how I can return an IEnumerable ?

Comment: `but I know when I use a List for temp the query will execute` what do you mean by that? You can just return `temp` and it should be fine (since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: The query will execute in the `foreach`. Why don't you want this query to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    return from item in db.tblAttachLabels select new AttachLabel()
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Text = item.Text
    };
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `using` statement here to dispose the context

Answer (score 1):

The other possibilty and an alternative to @haim770's answer is a loop with the [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword:

> When you use the yield keyword in a statement, you indicate that the method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an iterator. Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an explicit extra class (the class that holds the state for an enumeration, see IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the IEnumerable and IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
{               
    using(Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        foreach (var item in db.tblAttachLabels)
        {
            AttachLabel a = new AttachLabel()
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Text = item.Text
            };
            yield return a;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Your context should also be disposed so I've added a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

and there is no need for:

```
from al in db.tblAttachLabels select al;
```

because it just returns the same collection as `db.tblAttachLabels`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    var items = from al in db.tblAttachLabels select al;

    return items.Select(new AttachLabel()
    {
       ID = item.ID,
       Text = item.Text
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these, depending if you prefer lambda expressions:

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        return db.tblAttachLabels.Select(item => new AttachLabel
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            Text = item.Text
        });
    }
}
```

or not:

```
public static IEnumerable<AttachLabel> GetAttachLabel()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        return from item in db.tblAttachLabels
                select new AttachLabel
                {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Text = item.Text
                };
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of properties to map, have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)